# Oracle: how to select rows in table with colum change based on last update

Tags: oracle

I been trying to formulate my query but can't seem to get it.  I've tried to use rank() but I might be missing something.

Here is the sample data (there is more than 1 ID):

ID      Title                             Last_update_date
168  Prod. Manager    4/2/2016
168  Prod. Manager    3/28/2016
168  Supervisor             2/27/2016
168  Supervisor             2/15/2016
168  Supervisor             2/2/2016
168  Team Lead              1/14/2016
168  Team Lead              1/12/2016
168  Team Lead              1/10/2016
168  Supervisor             1/5/2016
168  Supervisor             1/2/2016
168  Developer               12/26/2015
168  Developer               12/15/2015

What I am trying to get in a query:

168  Prod. Manager     3/28/2016
168  Supervisor              2/2/2016
168  Team Lead               1/10/2016
168  Supervisor              1/2/2016
168  Developer                12/15/2015

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

RS

Comment: You are looking for an SQL query, correct?

Comment: PLease show what you have tried.

Comment: Hi, my initial query was exactly like mathguy.  But that will only output 3 rows because it was grouped by Id and Title, but there is the Last_Update_Date component to it.  I then started playing around with the rank() but with no success.  Requirements look simple but just could get it to output as required.

Comment: OK, this is a different requirement. You want to "start the clock" each time there is a change in Title, even if the same person had the same Title in the past (but there was another period when they had a different Title in between). This can be done but a little more complicated - will post my answer after I build and test it.

Comment: I hope this can be done with a query instead of writing a procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing purposes, I created a larger **table** (to include more than one id):

```
SQL> select * from your_table;

ID         TITLE                          LAST_UPDATE_DATE
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------
168        Prod. Manager                  04/02/2016
168        Prod. Manager                  03/28/2016
168        Supervisor                     02/27/2016
168        Supervisor                     02/15/2016
168        Supervisor                     02/02/2016
168        Team Lead                      01/14/2016
168        Team Lead                      01/12/2016
168        Team Lead                      01/10/2016
168        Supervisor                     01/05/2016
168        Supervisor                     01/02/2016
168        Developer                      12/26/2015
168        Developer                      12/15/2015
230        Supervisor                     03/03/2016
230        Supervisor                     02/23/2016
230        Team Lead                      02/14/2016
230        Team Lead                      02/01/2016
230        Supervisor                     01/03/2016

17 rows selected.
```

**Query:**

```
with a as
   (
      select id, title, last_update_date,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by last_update_date) - row_number()
                          over (partition by id, title order by last_update_date) gp
      from your_table
   )
select id, title, min(last_update_date) update_date
from a
group by id, title, gp
order by id, update_date desc
/
```

**Result:**

```
ID         TITLE                          UPDATE_DAT
---------- ------------------------------ ----------
168        Prod. Manager                  03/28/2016
168        Supervisor                     02/02/2016
168        Team Lead                      01/10/2016
168        Supervisor                     01/02/2016
168        Developer                      12/15/2015
230        Supervisor                     02/23/2016
230        Team Lead                      02/01/2016
230        Supervisor                     01/03/2016

8 rows selected.
```

**Explanation**:  This query is very similar to the earlier one. The only difficulty is to group by consecutive "title" designations, instead of grouping by title regardless of time line, for each id. This is achieved with the additional column "gp" calculated as a difference of row_number() over two different partitions. This is a very common and elementary technique, but perhaps not obvious at first sight; it is sometimes called the "tabibitosan method", google for it for more information.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I've been playing around with different ways to get the result.  I was trying to set a grouping of  Id, Title and Date range but wasn't able to do that.  Your query did it.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the need for analytic functions here (OldProgrammer's solution), when it's a trivial application of "group by."

```
    select    id, title, min(last_update_date)
    from      your_table   --  << -- enter your table name here
    group by  id, title
```

Comment: This was my initial query which gives 3 rows back.

Answer (score 1):

You need a subquery:
(EDIT: Untested)

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Last_update_date = 
   (SELECT MIN(Last_update_date) 
      FROM table t1 
     WHERE t1.Title = table.Title)
```

Alternately:

```
WITH T1 AS 
    (SELECT Title, MIN(Last_update_date) First_Update
       FROM table 
       GROUP BY Title)
SELECT table.* 
FROM table 
INNER JOIN T1 
  ON T1.First_Update = table.Last_update_date
 AND T1.Title = table.Title
```

Comment: Did you notice the requirement? There is ONLY ONE ID in the entire table. I don't see where you either join on or group by Title. Which also means you likely posted your solution without testing it... did you?

Comment: Edited my post and fixed that

Comment: Hi, actually, there is more than 1 Id in the table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT title,
    last_update_date,
    row_number() over (partition BY title order by last_update_date ) rn
  FROM test_table
  )
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Same thing here.  This only give 3 rows back.